I have GCC compiler added in user environment variables. Only C language shows output, on compiling C++ code, it does not show output. Why?
My gcc/g++ version is 14 (checked on command prompt). (mingw - w64)
Refer to these two images:
using notepad, cmd and gcc
using vs code with common extensions and gcc
Please give reason why hello, world is not shown in the output, even after compilation is successfully completed and executable file is made.
Image 1: It shows this 0xc00007b application error. Searched for it but could not find any leads.
I have done it on vs code as well (second image).
(Obviously, it's not because I am using F drive, I have tried in C and D drives).
And I am new to computer science, so please pardon.
I have tried to search solution for this problem but I could not.
Does this happen when we switch from C to C++ ?

Small point: the error code is actually 0xc000007b (5 0's) and that does produce hits within SO and on net from Microsoft.

This probably means that you one of the folders listed in your PATH environment variable has MinGW runtime dlls but the dlls are for the wrong 32 / 64 bit.

thanks, but i resolved it after a reinstall

A small warning that doing that could have broken software that relies on the 32 bit MinGW runtime depending on how it uses the runtime.

The 0xc00007b error on Windows typically indicates an invalid image format error. It occurs when there is a mismatch between 32-bit and 64-bit applications or dependencies.
Try linking statically C++ program
g++ -m64 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o helloworld.exe helloworld.cpp
g++ -m32 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o helloworld.exe helloworld.cpp

m32 or m64 depends on your needs(32 or 64 mits)

Small point - the error code has five 0's (OP error) which does help
when searching within SO and the net.

The 0xc000007b error in Windows is a "STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT" error. It occurs when an application tries to load an invalid or incompatible executable or DLL file.
Link statically or use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to see what is wrong.
